# SQL select statements in C#

Tags: c#

I am facing problem in executing the below code (*syntax error*). Please help me what should I do. Thanks.

Table columns: `pId, pAltId, pMobile, pDate, pName`

Variables: `argID, alt_ID, p_mobile, p_date, p_Name`

Statement:

```
String selectStr = "select * from " + thisTable + " where pId = '" + argID "+  OR  + 
pAltId = " + alt_ID "+ OR + pMobile =" + p_mobile "+ OR +  pDate =" + p_date "+ OR + 
pName = "+ p_Name "'";
```

Comment: What sort of problem?

Comment: One word: [**placeholders**](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html)

Comment: Not sure what your question is!

Comment: When you say "I have a problem" and you don't tell us what the problem is, it's really hard to help you solve it. You need to [edit] your question and explain what the problem is you're having if you want help here. (You also should actually ask a question while you're at it. There's not one in what you posted.)

Comment: Actually i am new to C# and i often use Stored Procedures for this kind of queries. But i tried the above line but not working....Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: Actually syntax is not correct.

Comment: Your quotes are all messed up.  For example: `"+ argID "+`

Answer (score 1):

In `+ " where pId = '" + argID "+` should the value for pId be in single quotes or not?  You have a starting ', but no ending.

Also you seem to be missing a number of double quotes or have them in the wrong place, are missing a number of spaces, and are missing the starting ' for pName.
Try:

```
String selectStr = "select * from " + thisTable + " where pId = " + argID + " " 
    + OR + " pAltId = " + alt_ID + " " + OR + " pMobile = " + p_mobile + " " 
    + OR + " pDate = '" + p_date + "' " + OR + " pName = '" + p_Name + "'";
```

If pMobile is a string then you will need to change `+ " pMobile = " + p_mobile + " "` to `+ " pMobile = '" + p_mobile + "' "`